# Python Tkinter: Bind function with labels in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm creating labels dynamically in a `for loop` using `tkinter`. I don't know how many labels will be created, but on clicking of each of the labels, a particular function must be called with a particular parameter.

To do this, I'm using this code:

```
for link in list_of_links:
    link_label = Label(self.video_window, text="Frame "+str(video_number), fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
    link_label.pack()
    link_label.place(x=xcod2, y=ycod2)
    link_label.bind("<1>", lambda x: self.goto_video_link(link))
```

Currently, I'm creating 10 labels. The problem is that on clicking any of the ten labels, the `goto_video_link` function seems to only use the 10th link.

If I click on the 5th label, I want it to use the 5th link.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda expressions are lazily evaluated, which means that `self.go_to_link(link)` is only evaluated when it is executed. In this moment `link` contains the value of the last link, so every button will go to the last link.

You need to force the evaluation of `link` during the for loop. This can be done with a lambda function that returns another lambda function with the value you want. I know it seems confusing, but the code below may make it clearer.

```
eval_link = lambda x: (lambda p: self.go_to_link(x))
for link in list_of_links:
    link_label = Label(self.video_window, text="Frame "+str(video_number), fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
    link_label.pack()
    link_label.place(x=xcod2, y=ycod2)
    link_label.bind("<1>", eval_link(link))
```

In this case, to be able to build the inner lambda it is necessary to evaluate `link`. Since it gets passed as a parameter, the inner most lambda is bound to the local copy `x` instead of `link` and since `x` is a local variable, it is always remade when the function is called.

Comment: When I did `eval_link = lambda x: (lambda: self.go_to_link(x))`, I got an error that said `TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)`. To correct that, I just had to change the `eval_link` to `eval_link = lambda x: (lambda p: self.go_to_link(x))` and then it worked.
Thank you!