# Tkinter labels not returning the proper value

Tags: python, tkinter

Using python 2.7 and Tkinter.
I am creating four lables in a loop and binding them to . I want the label to return
the name in the label's text. 
The problem is that no matter which label I press it returns the name in the last label.
I found this question [Python Tkinter: Bind function with labels in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714633/python-tkinter-bind-function-with-labels-in-for-loop) with exactly my problem but the solution given does not work for me even if I copied the code exactly.
Please anyone? here is my original code:

```
# labelbind.py
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Label choices')
root.geometry('1160x900+650+50')
root.option_readfile('setstyle2.txt')

def lblpress(x):
    print 'Label pressed', x
names = ['AMEX', 'CIBC', 'VISA', 'BMO']
col = 150
row = 45
num = 1
for name in names:
    bobo = 'lbl' + str(num)
    print bobo, name    
    bobo = Label(root, text = name)
    bobo.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x = name : lblpress(name))
    bobo.place(x = col, y = row)
    row += 40
    num += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything to the callback. The event object that is given to the callback contains a reference to the widget, and from the widget you can get the text.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def lblpress(event):
    print 'Label pressed:', event.widget.cget("text")

root = tk.Tk()

names = ['AMEX', 'CIBC', 'VISA', 'BMO']
for name in names:
    label = tk.Label(root, text=name)
    label.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lblpress)
    label.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Brian Oakley; I was very sure you would answer and you solved my problem. Tkinter documentation is like trying to decipher the Dead Sea papyrus... so many sources, so little consistency. Muchas gracias!